# Kafka Connect stops after 300k records

Tags: elasticsearch, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am trying to sink my mysql table to elasticsearch. My table has 1 million plus records. Issue is that my elasticsearch does not get anymore records after 300 some thousand records are inserted. I know that first time I ran it, it did run all the records. Its when I tried to do it again after deleting ES index, this happened. I have tried resetting the update_ts field to new timestamp. I have tried offset value in sink. Nothing seems to be working.

Here is my source file

```
{
        "name": "items3",
        "config": {
                "_comment": "The JDBC connector class. Don't change this if you want to use the JDBC Source.",
                "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",

                "_comment": "How to serialise the value of keys - here use the Confluent Avro serialiser. Note that the JDBC Source Connector always returns null for the key ",
                "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",

                "_comment": "Since we're using Avro serialisation, we need to specify the Confluent schema registry at which the created schema is to be stored. NB Schema Registry and Avro serialiser are both part of Confluent Open Source.",
                "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",

                "_comment": "As above, but for the value of the message. Note that these key/value serialisation settings can be set globally for Connect and thus omitted for individual connector configs to make them shorter and clearer",
                "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
                "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",


                "_comment": " --- JDBC-specific configuration below here  --- ",
                "_comment": "JDBC connection URL. This will vary by RDBMS. Consult your manufacturer's handbook for more information",
                "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?user=user&password=password",

                "_comment": "Which table(s) to include",
                "table.whitelist": "items",

                "_comment": "Pull all rows based on an timestamp column. You can also do bulk or incrementing column-based extracts. For more information, see http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/source_config_options.html#mode",
                "mode": "timestamp+incrementing",
  "incrementing.column.name": "id",
  "timestamp.column.name": "update_ts",


                "_comment": "If the column is not defined as NOT NULL, tell the connector to ignore this  ",
                "validate.non.null": "true",

                "_comment": "The Kafka topic will be made up of this prefix, plus the table name  ",
                "topic.prefix": "kafka-",
                "auto.offset.reset" : "earliest"
        }
}
```

And here is my sink

```
{
  "name": "items-sink",
  "config": {
    "_comment": "-- standard converter stuff -- this can actually go in the worker config globally --",
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",


    "_comment": "--- Elasticsearch-specific config ---",
    "_comment": "Elasticsearch server address",
    "connection.url": "http://localhost:9200",
     "_comment": "Elasticsearch mapping name. Gets created automatically if doesn't exist  ",
    "type.name": "items",

    "_comment": "Which topic to stream data from into Elasticsearch",
    "topics": "kafka-items",
        "auto.offset.reset" : "earliest",
    "_comment": "If the Kafka message doesn't have a key (as is the case with JDBC source)  you need to specify key.ignore=true. If you don't, you'll get an error from the Connect task: 'ConnectException: Key is used as document id and can not be null.",
    "key.ignore": "true"
  }
}
```

as you can see I am trying to auto.offset.reset to earliest so if it is keeping track of my records somehow, it will start over, but all in vain.

Answer (score 0):

`"auto.offset.reset" : "earliest"` can only be used inside the `connect-distributed.properties` file, not the JSON connector configurations

And in that file, since it's a consumer configuration, it's named `consumer.auto.offset.reset`.

Also, the consumer group is mapped to the `name` field of the connector configuration, so unless that's changed, you'd be continuing to consume from where the previous one of the same name left off until the group offsets are reset or the name is changed. By default, the group name is `connect-${connector_name}`